# how to update a column with predefined rank based on new record's rank?

Tags: sql-update, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access 2010 application which writes back to (backend) sql server.The table has student id, test score and rank as columns. The application has a form, which takes input from users.  When a new student enters his/her ID, score and rank, based on inserted rank the rest of the ranks must be updated.

For eg, if a new student has a score 79, and rank 5, the current student at 5 must be changed to 6, sixth rank to seventh and so on, in the SQL table

Before:

```
Student_ID  Score Rank
1            89    1
16           88    2
25           84    3
3            81    4
7            78    5
15           75    6
12           72    7
17           70    8
56           65    9
9            64    10
```

After:

```
Student_ID  Score Rank
1            89    1
16           88    2
25           84    3
3            81    4
7            78    6
15           75    7
12           72    8
17           70    9
56           65    10
9            64    11
10           75    5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the rank field and create a query that calculates the rank (row number) on the fly. To speed this up, use a collection as shown here:

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```

Study the in-line comments for typical usage.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Instead of using 1,2,3... I used 10,20,30.. so on as rank. This helped in adding new student ranks in between. Considering the fact that this table is seldom updated, this method worked fine.